# Mongodb aggregate $limit does not return a document

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I must to use limit but when i use this aggregate does not return a document:

```
db.users.aggregate(
[
 {$limit: 1 },
 { $lookup: 
    { from: "usersmeta", localField: "_id", foreignField: "user", as: "metas" }
 },
 { $match: 
    { phoneverifyed: true, adminallowed: true}
 },
 {$sort: {_id:1}}
])
```

What is wrong?

**Tip**: when i set $limit to a large number like 999999999 returns all documents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mongodb executes stages in order, in your case you limited your scope to a single user at the beginning of your pipeline so what you need to do is to move your limit aggregation to the bottom of your aggregations list.